# error CS0103: The name 'OnSelectEnter' does not exist in the current context

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I am following this Unity Vr YT. tutorial video about a gun mechanic, but I get this error? Can someone help me?
(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IX2EUAcocoM&t)

Thanks for your help:

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.XR.Interaction.Toolkit;

public class Weapon : XRGrabInteractable
{
    private GripHold gripHold = null;

    private XRBaseInteractor gripHand = null;

    private readonly Vector3 gripRotation = new Vector3(45, 0, 0);

    protected override void Awake()
    {
        base.Awake();
        SetupHolds();

        onSelectEnter.AddListener(SetInitialRotation);
    }

    private void SetupHolds()
    {
        gripHold = GetComponentInChildren<GripHold>();
        gripHold.Setup(this);
    }

    private void SetupExtras()
    {

    }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        onSelectEnter.RemoveListener(SetInitialRotation);
    }

    private void SetInitialRotation(XRBaseInteractor interactor)
    {
        Quaternion newRotation = Quaternion.Euler (gripRotation);
        interactor.attachTransform.localRotation = newRotation;
    }

    public void SetGripHand(XRBaseInteractor interactor)
    {
        gripHand = interactor;
        OnSelectEnter(gripHand);
    }

    public void ClearGripHand(XRBaseInteractor interactor)
    {
        gripHand = null;
        OnSelectExit(interactor);
    }

    public void SetGuardHand(XRBaseInteractor interactor)
    {

    }

    public void ClearGuardHand(XRBaseInteractor interactor)
    {

    }

    public override void ProcessInteractable(XRInteractionUpdateOrder.UpdatePhase updatePhase)
    {
        base.ProcessInteractable(updatePhase);
    }

    private void SetGripRotation()
    {

    }

    private void CheckDistance(XRBaseInteractor interactor, HandHold handHold)
    {

    }

    public void PullTrigger()
    {

    }

    public void ReleaseTrigger()
    {

    }

    public void ApplyRecoil()
    {

    }
}
```

- 

*(This is just some test az more details because I can't post it. Sory if something missing
A szőke fiú leereszkedett a sziklafok néhány utolsó méterén,
s elindult a lagúna felé. Noha levetette iskolai szvetterét, s a fél
kezével maga után húzta a földön, átizzadt, szürke inge a testéhez
ragadt, haja is homlokára tapadt. Körülötte a dzsungelbe benyúló
hosszú nyiladék forró volt, mint a gőzfürdő. Nehézkesen botladozott a
kúszónövények és a ledőlt fatörzsek között, amikor
boszorkánysivításszerű hangot hallatva hirtelen egy madár vágódott
fel előtte, mint egy vörössárga látomás; a sivításra egy másik hang
felelt.

)*

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version you probably rather mean either [`OnSelectEntered`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.xr.interaction.toolkit@1.0/api/UnityEngine.XR.Interaction.Toolkit.XRBaseInteractable.html#UnityEngine_XR_Interaction_Toolkit_XRBaseInteractable_OnSelectEntered_UnityEngine_XR_Interaction_Toolkit_XRBaseInteractor_)

> This method is called by the Interaction Manager when the Interactor first initiates selection of an Interactable in a second pass.

or [`OnSelectEntering`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.xr.interaction.toolkit@1.0/api/UnityEngine.XR.Interaction.Toolkit.XRBaseInteractable.html#UnityEngine_XR_Interaction_Toolkit_XRBaseInteractable_OnSelectEntering_UnityEngine_XR_Interaction_Toolkit_XRBaseInteractor_)

> This method is called by the Interaction Manager right before the Interactor first initiates selection of an Interactable in a first pass.

---

Or if you actually are to call the event manually then it is a lower case [`onSelectEntered`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.xr.interaction.toolkit@1.0/api/UnityEngine.XR.Interaction.Toolkit.XRBaseInteractable.html#UnityEngine_XR_Interaction_Toolkit_XRBaseInteractable_onSelectEntered), [`onSelectEnter`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.xr.interaction.toolkit@1.0/api/UnityEngine.XR.Interaction.Toolkit.XRBaseInteractable.html#UnityEngine_XR_Interaction_Toolkit_XRBaseInteractable_onSelectEnter) or - as the first two are deprecated now - just [`selectEnter`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.xr.interaction.toolkit@1.0/api/UnityEngine.XR.Interaction.Toolkit.XRBaseInteractable.html#UnityEngine_XR_Interaction_Toolkit_XRBaseInteractable_selectEnter) depending on your version.